# Swift 3. Argument Labels do not match error

Tags: swift3

I have just upgraded to Swift 3 and get an error on the following code that is within  a UITableViewController.

The code is return segue from a form, and is intended to refresh the table inserting the new entry from the form. This worked fine on 2.2, and I have changed NSIndexPath to IndexPath

```
@IBAction func saveTripFormViewList(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){
    trips = uiRealm.objects(Trip.self)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(forRow: trips!.count - 1, inSection: 0)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

The error I get is

```
Argument labels '(forRow:, inSection:)' do not match any available overloads
```

Any advice on how to resolve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 it's just IndexPath(row:section:).

FYI, IndexPath is a new value type (a struct) that does the same job as NSIndexPath (a class). (NSIndexPath's initializer has changed as well.) Also, I believe they're toll-free bridged, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, if change the syntax to  
let indexPath = IndexPath(Row: trips.count - 1, Section: 0). I still get an error about lists not matching overloads.

Comment: @MichaelMoulsdale No capitals, just lowercase row and section